# Cannot Resolve Symbol When Trying to Using Spark Aggregation Function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I want to try something like

[image: the picture]

However, I got a warning from idea like
[image]

what should I do?

Comment: Please post the code and error as code formatted text in the question and not as pictures.

Answer (score 4):

Your import statement should be `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

where `._` is a wildcard import. `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` object defines built-in standard functions to work with.

Then you can use the functions like this:

```
df.groupBy(df("pt")).agg(max("id"), mean("encodedType")).show
```

You can check the example at this [link](https://github.com/bhardwajpawan/spark-learning/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/spark/learning/chapter3/AggregateAPI.scala#L25)